# Windows executable can't see output of PowerShell command

Tags: powershell

This works:

```
PS> $serviceName = Get-WmiObject Win32_service -filter "displayname = 'Security Center'" |select -expandproperty name
PS> sc.exe start $serviceName
```

This doesn't - it's as if the pipeline variable `$_` isn't being passed to `sc.exe`:

```
PS> Get-WmiObject Win32_service -filter "displayname = 'Security Center'" |select -expandproperty name |sc.exe start "$_"
DESCRIPTION:
        Starts a service running.
USAGE:
        sc <server> start [service name] <arg1> <arg2> ...
```

What am I missing to make this work as a oneliner? I've tried pretty much everything I can think of (scriptblocks et cetera) but nothing seems to succeed.

Comment: `$_` doesn't exist in the context in which you're trying to use it (see Mathias R. Jessen's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_` doesn't magically work in the calling scope. Wrap the `sc.exe` statement in a `ForEach-Object` scriptblock:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_service -filter "displayname = 'Security Center'" |select -expandproperty name |ForEach-Object {
  sc.exe start "$_"
}
```

Comment: Arghhh, I *knew* it was something simple I was missing - it always is with PowerShell! Thanks!